# Isomorphism of quotients of powers of maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be an integral domain, and $\mathfrak{m}$ a maximal ideal of $R$.  Let $R_\mathfrak{m}$ denote the ring localized at $\mathfrak{m}$, and let $\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{m}R_\mathfrak{m}$ denote the maximal ideal of $R_\mathfrak{m}$.

Then we have an isomorphism $$R/\mathfrak{m}^n \cong R_\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}^n,$$ for $n \geq 1$.  (See for example Neukirch, *Algebraic Number Theory*, pg. 66).

**My question:**

Can this result extend to an isomorphism
$$\mathfrak{m}^k/\mathfrak{m}^n \cong \mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}^k/\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}^n,$$
for $1 \leq k \leq n$?  It would seem the proof goes through, but I wanted to check with the experts, since I hadn't seen this result explicitly written down before.

**2nd question (added later):**

Is the "integral domain" condition really necessary to either Neukirch's result or the other one I suggested?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, $\mathfrak{m}^k/\mathfrak{m}^n \cong \mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}^k/\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}^n$.

This immediately results from the commutative diagram 
$$\begin{array}
00 & \longrightarrow \mathfrak{m}^k/\mathfrak{m}^n\longrightarrow & R/\mathfrak{m}^n & \longrightarrow & R/\mathfrak{m}^k& \longrightarrow 0\\
& \quad \quad \downarrow & \downarrow \cong  & & \downarrow \cong\\
0 &\longrightarrow  \mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}^k/\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}^n\longrightarrow   & R_\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}^n & \longrightarrow & R_\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}^k& \longrightarrow 0  
\end{array}
$$  Since you know that the the two rightmost vertical maps are isomorphisms, the leftmost vertical map is also an isomorphism, by the snake lemma (say).

Comment: Thanks!  That's very nice.

Comment: You are welcome, John.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest a different approach in order to prove that $\mathfrak{m}^k/\mathfrak{m}^n \simeq \mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}^k/\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}^n$ which also contains the case $k=0$.

Obviously $\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}^k/\mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{m}^n$ is isomorphic to $S^{-1}(\mathfrak{m}^k/\mathfrak{m}^n)$, where $S=R-\mathfrak m$. If we set $M=\mathfrak{m}^k/\mathfrak{m}^n$ we have to prove that $M\simeq S^{-1}M$. But $\mathfrak m^tM=0$ for $t=n-k\ge 1$, and thus $M$ is in fact an $\overline R=R/\mathfrak m^t$-module. Now we can replace $S$ by $\overline S=\overline R-\overline{\mathfrak m}$ and let us see what we have now:

> $\overline R$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\overline{\mathfrak m}$, $\overline S=\overline R-\overline{\mathfrak m}$, and $M$ an $\overline R$-module. We want to prove that $M\simeq\overline{S}^{-1}M$.

But there is nothing to prove once we note that $\overline S=U(\overline R)$.

Comment: Thanks.  Perhaps you could elaborate a bit on why $M\simeq\overline{S}^{-1}M$ implies $M\simeq S^{-1}M$?  Is that automatic?  Or is there something to show there?

Comment: @JohnM $S^{-1}M$ is isomorphic to $\overline{S}^{-1}M$ canonically, that is, by sending $x/s$ to $x/\overline s$. (Take into account that $\overline ax:=ax$.)

Answer (score 4):

Well I found this result in Milne's [Commutative Algebra](http://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/CA.pdf) notes, Prop 5.8, and the ring need not be either Noetherian or an integral domain.

Comment: Nevertheless, thanks for your answer and posting the diagram!